# How to get an boomerang-effect in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to create an boomerang effect in as3
I have little experience and I have found this code:

```
TweenLite.to(man, 1, {x:241.3, y:372.8, rotation:360});
```

using greensock but I want the object go back, I can use throwproms from geensock but than I need to become a member and I don't want to spend allot of money, can someone help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will give you the desired effect, but something like...

```
var tween = TweenLite.to(man, 1, {
    x:241.3,
    y:372.8,
    rotation:360,
    onComplete: function() { tween.reverse(); } 
});
```

Comment: @@AndySavage thx but it needs to come back on an other x variable

Comment: Then change reverse for your desired tween.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onComplete` param in greensock to call reverse tween right after forward one. It should look something like this

```
var myTween = TweenLite.to(man, 1, {x:241.3, y:372.8, rotation:360,
    onComplete: function(){myTween.reverse()}
});
```

The key must be in usign right easing function.

If you want to use another coordinates to go back, for example, back to player new coordinates, than it could be something like this

```
var myTween = TweenLite.to(man, 1, {x:241.3, y:372.8, rotation:360,
    onComplete:boomerangBack,onCompleteParams:[man]}
});
function boomerangBack(obj){
    TweenLite.to(obj, 1, {x:obj.x, y:obj.y, rotation:720});
}
```